# Heavy class as a Service

Tags: java, web-services, client-server, ipc

I have a class that performs some very heavy computation and requires a lot ammounts of RAM. Basically, the problem is RAM since it does require around 5GB of RAM. I have two computers available. 
My idea is the following:

1. Create a service on the powerful machine that will have the heavy
   class loaded.
2. Create a client on the less powerful laptop that will
   send requests to the Class Service and gather the required results.

Now that I have implemented this I face the following problem:
Since thousands of HTTP requests are generated per second there is very heavy overhead due to connection open/close. Thus, the performance is still bad.

Is there any more clever way to face the above issue?
Would the idea of using a simple socket be useful?
One idea that I have for now is to perform request caching (e.g. Gather 10000 requests and send only one to the class service. The response will contain data for all the 10000 requests).

Comment: the only way is to reduce amount of data sent and received (*C.O. on duty*). Without knowing your exact architecture and data model, it is impossible to suggest any solution.

Comment: That's hard to say without knowing more about what that service does and how it does it (and all that information would probably be way to much for SO anyways). However, instead of caching 10000 requests I'd first check why there are so many requests and whether it would be possible combine them on the client already.

Comment: The service performs Word2Vec calculation. That is, for every word it returns a vector of 300 doubles. However, I am sending an HTML request for every word on the pool. My collection has ~ 50K documents with ~1000 words each. The result is 50M requests. However, in order to process the document N the N-1 should be processed. This is why I think of keeping an active socket connection.